# Local conectedness at infinity in Alexandroff compactification

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $G\subset \mathbb{C}$ be a domain and let $G^*$ be its one point compactification. Moreover suppose $F$ is a relatively closed subset of $G$. I am trying to uncover what local connectedness of $G^*\setminus F$ at infinity means.

I know local connectedness of $G^*\setminus F$ at infinity should mean: For every neighborhood $\infty\in U\subset G^*\setminus F$, there exist a connected neighborhood $V\subset U$ such that $\infty \in V.$

However this seems to not be the case. If we set $G=\mathbb{C}$ and $F=\mathbb{R}$, I know that $G^*\setminus F$ is supposed to be locally connected at infinity.
However I can't see why. For example the set $U = \lbrace z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|>1, z\not\in\mathbb{R}\rbrace$ then $U$ is an open set since it is the compliment of the compact unit disc in $G^*\setminus F$. However any neighborhood $\infty\in V\subset U$ is not connected since it is divided in two part one over and one under the real line. Thus from my understanding it shouldn't be locally connected.

Anyway obviously something I am saying is wrong, any help would be highly appreciated. Also what would be an intuitive way to figure out if $G^*\setminus F$ is locally connected at infinity.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't in your example the infinity point the one that "connects" the two parts?

Comment: @radekzak I see. If $G=\mathbb{C}$ then I guess  the only way to not be locally connected at infinity is only if the set $F$ is the union of infinite "cocentric" closed curves whose union is unbounded?